# using EJS to render google maps api on webpage

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, google-maps, ejs

I am using EJS to render google maps api on a webpage.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script>
    var map;

    function initMap() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
          lat: -34.397,
          lng: 150.644
        },
        zoom: 8
      });
    }
  </script>

  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap" async defer>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I am getting 200's in my network tab but nothing is rendering on the page, am i doing something wrong with the syntax?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
</script>

<script>
function initialize() {
  var mapProp = {
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
    zoom:5,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Might be worth indicating where this came from/why this works for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

you must fix style = "height:xx";
at your html, body and  #map
they are set to 0 by default